# Cannot get the list of the modes of an app

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I can't do a foreach with my response

I already tried many things but nothing resolved it

```php
/**
* Show the application dashboard.
*
* @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
*/
public function index()
{
  $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
  $effects = [];
  $res = $client->request('GET', 'http://85.171.71.189/get_modes');
  $effects = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);
  return view('base.effects', [ 'effects' => $effects ]);
}
```

```php
@if($effects)
  @foreach($effects as $effect)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $effect['mode'] }}</td>
      <td>{{ $effect['name'] }}</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Activate</button></td>
    <tr>
  @endforeach
@else
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">No effects found.</td>
  </tr>
@endif
```

I expect that I have a table with all modes inside, but the actual error is

> Undefined index: name (View: H:\wamp64\www\scintillement\resources\themes\light\base\effects.blade.php)

Comment: dd($effects) in your controller and check if the name index exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```php
@forelse ($effects as $effect)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ isset($effect['mode']) ? $effect['mode'] : '--' }}</td>           
        <td>{{ isset($effect['name'] ? $effect['name'] : '--' }}</td>                
        <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Activate</button></td>
    <tr>
@empty
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">No effects found.</td>
    </tr>
@endforelse
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
 @if($effects)
                  @foreach($effects as $effect)
                      <tr>
                        @if(isset($effect['mode']))
                        <td>{{ $effect['mode'] }}</td>
                        @else
                        <td>-</td>
                        @endif
                        @if(isset($effect['name']))
                        <td>{{ $effect['name'] }}</td>
                        @else
                        <td>-</td>
                        @endif
                        <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Activate</button></td>
                      <tr>
                  @endforeach
                @else
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">No effects found.</td>
                  </tr>
                @endif
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Yes this working but my code is clean :)) @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd

Answer (score 1):

There were some empty rows in get from the *http://85.171.71.189/get_modes*

You can handle it by adding condition of empty or not before displaying in the table

```
@if($effects)
@foreach($effects as $effect)
    @if(!empty($effect)) // new condition added
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $effect['mode'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $effect['name'] }}</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Activate</button></td>
        <tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
```